# Как сделать связь между таблицами one-to-one в Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Как сделать миграцию и модели, где связь один к одному.
Например, две модели: `user` и `address`.

Связь должна быть от пользователя к адресу, чтоб можно было сделать так: `user.create_address(*)`

И так: `user.address.city`.

Я не знаю в чем разница `has_one` и `belongs_to`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разница в том, что это две стороны одной связи. Кто кому принадлежит - определяете согласно логике и здравому смыслу. "Адрес принадлежит пользователю" звучит нормально, "пользователь принадлежит адресу" - так себе.

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :address
end
```

В таблице `addresses` должно быть поле `user_id` соответственно